# Example project showing how to send bluetooth data from a computer to Android phone

Tags: android, bluetooth

One part of the project we are trying to undertake involves sending a message over bluetooth from a computer to an android phone.  I was wondering if anyone has done something like this already who might be able to share some example code with us.

Thanks 
Fernando

Answer (score 1):

I would highly recommend checking out the following example: [BluetoothChat @ developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/BluetoothChat/index.html)

I did a project a few months back where we designed a body-worn, wireless sensor board that would send readings to an Android phone over Bluetooth, and this example got me started. I apologize, but I cannot share my exact code at the moment.

The example allows two Android phones to chat with one another over Bluetooth and prints the messages to the screen. With a few changes to this example, you can send the raw data you need instead of user input. The BluetoothChatService class in that example ([seen here](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/BluetoothChat/src/com/example/android/BluetoothChat/BluetoothChatService.html)) handles all the ugly stuff (listening for connections, connecting, etc) for you.

Good luck!